# Redirect Magento index.php in subdirectory to main domain - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url, redirect

I have a site at www.mywebsite.com AND I have my Magento site in a sub dir at www.mywebsite.com/store

I'm trying to redirect the Magento homepage (and only that homepage) --  www.mywebsite.com/store and www.mywebsite.com/store/index.php to www.mywebsite.com

Trying to do this via htaccess.  Any help is much appreciated!

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^store$ http://www.mywebsite.local [R=302]
RewriteRule ^store/$ http://www.mywebsite.local [R=302]
RewriteRule ^store/index.php$ http://www.mywebsite.local [R=302]
RewriteRule ^store/index.php/$ http://www.mywebsite.local [R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^store$ http://www.mywebsite.com [R=302]
RewriteRule ^store/$ http://www.mywebsite.com [R=302]
RewriteRule ^store/index.php$ http://www.mywebsite.com [R=302]
RewriteRule ^store/index.php/$ http://www.mywebsite.com [R=302]
```

Change `R=302` to `R=301` when you are sure the redirect works

Comment: What happens when you try go to the `store` or `store/index.php`?

Comment: store redirects correctly, however store/index.php just stays on that same page.

Comment: Can you try hard fresh the `store/index.php` page (or try in a different browser)?

Comment: Edited code according to your changes and interestingly, it's only redirecting from /store on FireFox.  On google Chrome inognito, neither are redirecting properly.

Comment: Additionally, I added a copy of my htaccess file in original post.

Comment: That htaccess file, is it in the `store` directory or the root directory? My code above should be in the root directory.

Comment: Yes, put your code in root directory of htaccess file and still no luck.  I tried the following rule but it redirects any url in `store/`  `RewriteEngine on
Redirect /store/index.php http://www.mywebsite.com/` Any other ideas?

Comment: So which pages are being redirected?

Comment: With the rule I just wrote, it's redirecting anything in `store/` back to homepage

Answer (score 0):

Was able to finally acheive using a url rewrite in Magento.

[image]

Thank you for your help